# SonarQube vulnerabilty in Java Singleton Class-- Static Objects must be avoided, move to local members to avoid global state

Tags: java, sonarqube, singleton, dao, static-analysis

```
private static IaddRegionDao iaddRegionDao=null;

public static IaddRegionDao getInstance()
{
    if(iaddRegionDao == null)
    {
        iaddRegionDao = new IaddRegionDaoImpl();
    }
    return iaddRegionDao;
}
```

My code above is a singleton class for Database Connection. But in SonarQube the code quality check is giving me the following error:

> Static Objects must be avoided, move to local members to avoid global state

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marked this as a false positive. Valid scenario..